# How to get section header from UItableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to get section header view using this code:

```
[tableView headerViewForSection:indexPath.section];
```

but this code always returns me nil.
Could you give me some examples to get section header view from table view?
This is my viewForHeader implementation:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

  DynamicHeader *headerView = [[DynamicHeader alloc] init];
        headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40);
        UILabel *headerLbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        headerLbl.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 20);
        if(((SectionViewController *)sharedInstance.currentViewController).currentSectionType == 25)
        {
            UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"minus.png"]];
            imgView.frame = CGRectMake(285, 14.5, 16, 13);
            [headerView addSubview:imgView];
            UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:sharedInstance action:@selector(headerTap:)];
            [headerView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
            headerView.tableView = tableView;
            headerView.heightForRows = 95;
            headerView.isOpen = YES;
        }
 headerLbl.text = [[[[[((SectionViewController *)sharedInstance.currentViewController).responseDictionary valueForKey:DATA_PARAMETER] valueForKey:SECTION_TABLE_PARAMETER] objectAtIndex:section] valueForKey:TABLE_SECTION_HEADER] capitalizedString];
 [headerView addSubview:headerLbl];

        return headerView;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 if((DynamicHeader *)[tableView headerViewForSection:indexPath.section] != nil)
        {
            return ((DynamicHeader *)[tableView headerViewForSection:indexPath.section]).heightForRows;
        }
        else
        {
            return 95;
        }

}


- (void)headerTap: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    DynamicHeader *view = (DynamicHeader *)[recognizer view];
    if(view.isOpen)
    {
        view.heightForRows = 0;

    }
    else
    {
        view.heightForRows = 95;
    }
    view.isOpen = !view.isOpen;

    [view.tableView beginUpdates];
    [view.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Have you used defined - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section to assign view?

Comment: What (if any) is your implementation of `headerViewForSection:`?

Comment: In that case it seems that your `tableview` object is `nil` at the time you are calling this method. Or it's `delegate` had not yet been set (by you). Because `tableview` calls it's `delegate` method - it does not implement its own.

Comment: @rokjarc, At the moment I am calling this method tableview is not nil. Also, I set tableview delegate and datasource.

Comment: I see: it seems the problem is in your `heightForRowAtIndexPath` - there should not be a `if((DynamicHeader *)[tableView headerViewForSection:indexPath.section] != nil)` condition

Comment: @rokjarc, I set this condition for those case when this method called first time and section header view is not created yet.

Comment: Yes, but tableview calls this method to check if it needs to call viewForHeader at all - since you return 0 it doesn't even try to create header view

Comment: Could you find a solution? Having the same issue - headers are visible, indices correct but this method always returns nil.

Answer (score 8):

Quite old question, but maybe a solution is helpful to others too...

An UITableView does create cell, header and footer views only if they are needed (e.g. they are visible in the table view content area).

If the cell, header or footer view isn't visible in the table view, a call to '**cellForRowAtIndexPath:**', '**headerViewForSection:**' or '**footerViewForSection:**' might return '**nil**'.
(See UITableView.h for documentation of this behaviour. The only exception would be, that the view has not jet been recycled by the table view)

Of course you can create any table view subview by calling the responsible delegate method directly, but UITableView wouldn't do so by itself.

So the solution to access a cell, header oder footer view is to make it visible in the table view first.

***An example for an header view:***

```
CGRect  sectionHeaderRect = [self.tableView rectForHeaderInSection:groupSectionIndex];
[self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:sectionHeaderRect
                           animated:NO];

// Let the tableview load the needed views
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    UITableViewHeaderFooterView*    groupSectionHeaderView = [self.tableView headerViewForSection:sectionIndex];

    // Use groupSectionHeaderView
});
```

Comment: In my case it always returns nil despite the header is visible and the index correct.

Answer (score 3):

Use this delegate method to access the header view:

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section`

Answer (score 2):

Have you implemented

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

in your ViewController subclass?

And if yes, probably you have some problem in one of these methods.

Comment: @KiselAlexander, is calling cellForRowAtIndexPath instead also returns nil?

Comment: so look at your implementation of viewForHeaderInSection, I think, the problem is there. Do you see the header at runtime?

Comment: nik, should I use dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier in viewForHeaderInSection?

Answer (score 1):

Your header view must inherit from `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` or else this call will not work and always returns nil.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling `[tableView headerViewForSection:indexPath.section];`?

If you are calling it in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` before the tableView is visible then you will get nil back as the tableView is not setup yet.

If you call it else where once the tableView is loaded, you should get a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` back.

Comment: I am calling [tableView headerViewForSection:indexPath.section]; in heightForRowAtIndexPath when tableview is already visible.

Comment: Yes, calling this in heightForRow returns nil for me, too. I suspect the header is not set up/being refreshed when the tableview calculates the cell heights. It doesn't on cell touch events, however. If you have a custom header view, perhaps you could create an IBOutlet to it?

Answer (score -1):

`heightForRowAtIndexPath` called before `viewForHeaderInSection` so of course you will get `nil`.

Comment: I am calling heightForRowAtIndexPath several times. Once when I create tableview and then when I call [tableview beginUpdates]. In second case I already have header for section.

Comment: Will you please tell what is the need of calling headerViewForSection in heightForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: I have custom section header view which contains height for all cells in this section. I do not want have additional variables in my main class, so I keep height in header view.