# IOS swift tableview get headerview for a section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, nstableheaderview

Following is my code to add header to section

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let optionsForSection = isMutliLevelOptions() ? options : optionsList?[section]
    let sectionView = MenuOptionHeaderView()
    sectionView.isMultiSelectAllowed = allowsMultipleSelection(section)
    sectionView.selectedOptionsCount = getSelectedCount(section)
    sectionView.option = optionsForSection
    sectionView.setUI()
    //headerView = sectionView
    return sectionView
}
```

Following is code to access header of a section

```
  func updateHeader(section : Int) {
    let headerView : MenuOptionHeaderView = optionsTableView.headerView(forSection: section) as! MenuOptionHeaderView
    headerView.selectedOptionsCount = getSelectedCount(section)
    headerView.setUI()
}
```

But above code is crashing saying **Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Also I am getting warning **Cast from 'UITableViewHeaderFooterView?' to unrelated type 'MenuOptionHeaderView' always fails** at for my code

I am creating MenuOptionHeaderView using .xib file and is working fine **I want to know how can I get header for a particular section**

Following is code MenuOptionHeaderView

```
import UIKit

class MenuOptionHeaderView: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var optionNameLbl: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var selectMinLbl: UILabel!



@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!


var option : Options?
var selectedOptionsCount = 0
var isMultiSelectAllowed = false
override init(frame: CGRect) {
   super.init(frame: frame)
   commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   super.init(coder: aDecoder)
   commonInit()
}

func commonInit() {
   Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MenuOptionHeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)
   contentView.fixInView(self)
}


func setUI() {


    optionNameLbl.text = isMultiSelectAllowed ?  "\(option?.name ?? "")(\(selectedOptionsCount))" :  (option?.name ?? "")


}


}
```

Comment: for which line you are getting that error or crash?

Comment: let headerView : MenuOptionHeaderView = optionsTableView.headerView(forSection: section) as! MenuOptionHeaderView

Comment: Hope it helps -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231726/uitableview-headerviewforsection-always-returns-nil

Comment: You haven't defined `optionsTableView` in your code you shared. So if it is `nil` you will get a crash.

Comment: This can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882561/how-to-get-section-header-from-uitableview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your view `MenuOptionHeaderView` must inherit from `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` or else this call :

```
optionsTableView.headerView(forSection: section) as! MenuOptionHeaderView
```

will not work and always returns nil.

Source : [How to get section header from UItableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882561/how-to-get-section-header-from-uitableview)

Answer (score 0):

1. You should inherit your custom header view from `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`.

```
class MenuOptionHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
   ....

   static var nib:UINib {
      return UINib(nibName: identifier, bundle: ZohoSearchKit.frameworkBundle)
   }

   static var identifier: String {
        return String(describing: self)
   }
}
```

2. Use `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView` , So, that your header view won't be created every time. it will improve your scrolling performance.

   2.1 register your header view in UITableview.

   ```
    optionsTableView.register(MenuOptionHeaderView.nib,forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: MenuOptionHeaderView.identifier)
   ```

   2.2 Reuse headerview

   ```
   if let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: MenuOptionHeaderView.identifier) as? MenuOptionHeaderView {
    ....
   }
   ```